# yeoman grunt build does not deploy component css

Tags: css, ember.js, yeoman, gruntjs, bower

I'm new to Yeoman.  I've generated an Ember.js project with

```
$ yo ember
```

so I needed to install Twitter Bootstrap separately running

```
$ bower install bootstrap
```

but running

```
$ grunt build
```

does not deploy the component css files to the dist/styles directory in the same way that it does for js files to dist/scripts

How do I include component css files in my project distribution and reference them in my html?

Answer (score 8):

When you are integrating the css in your html files you usually do it like this (I use bootstrap as example):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/bootstrap-2.3.2.min.css">
```

If you run `grunt build`this won't deploy the css files. To have them deployed in your project  wrap it in the `usemin` comments, just like you do with the javascript stuff:

```
<!-- build:css styles/bootstrap.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/bootstrap-2.3.2.min.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This will then deploy this css file as `styles/bootstrap.css` in your `dist` folder and update the references in your html files just like it does with the javascript references.

Answer (score 1):

I recently [added support for Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember/commit/2ad6633a406956fccbd75f4e4f7c80089d65f897) to the generator, so if you upgrade to the latest version you will get a prompt for it.

In general, if you want to reference components, you should not copy them around to the `styles` or `scripts` folder but link directly to the components folder, e. g.

`<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-affix.js"></script>`

Otherwise, you lose all the benefits of using a package manager except for the easier initial installation.

Comment: Running the follow commands does not prompt me to include twitter bootstrap.  Am I missing a step?
`$ npm install -g generator-ember
$ yo ember`

Referencing CSS in this way does not seem to result in CSS being included in the dist/styles directory.  Should CSS be reverenced in the same way?
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/bootstrap/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" />`

Comment: There hasn't been a new release of `generator-ember` yet, so you have to manually it via `npm install -g https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember/archive/master.tar.gz` or apply the changes manually that were made in the linked commit.